# pcl include convolution not working

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library

I am trying to use the convolution library in pcl (point cloud library). The page for the Gaussian Convolution page is [here](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1filters_1_1_gaussian_kernel.html). It quotes the following include for this library:

```
#include <pcl/filters/convolution_3d.h>
```

But when I include the above file I get the following compile error:

```
fatal error: pcl/filters/convolution_3d.h: No such file or directory
```

Other includes from the filters file like:

```
#include <pcl/filters/radius_outlier_removal.h>
#include <pcl/filters/conditional_removal.h>
```

Works just fine, so why does the convolution library not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That functionality is only in the trunk version (1.6), so this could be explained by only having the 1.5.1 version installed, or possibly not having the right -I/-L flags for the compiler to see the trunk version first, assuming you have both installed.